# combineLatest doesn't emit anything unless all inner observables have emitted at least 1 emission

Tags: rxjs

So say I have these 3 observables:

```
const numpad1$ = fromEvent(document, 'keydown')
.pipe(
    startWith(0),
    filter(({ key, code }) => key === '1' && code === 'Numpad1'),
    map(() => 1),
    scan((a, b) => a + b, 0),
);

const numpad2$ = fromEvent(document, 'keydown')
    .pipe(
        startWith(0),
        filter(({ key, code }) => key === '2' && code === 'Numpad2'),
        map(() => 1),
        scan((a, b) => a + b),
    );

const numpad3$ = fromEvent(document, 'keydown')
    .pipe(
        startWith(0),
        filter(({ key, code }) => key === '3' && code === 'Numpad3'),
        map(() => 1),
        scan((a, b) => a + b),
    );
```

Then I use `combineLatest` like this:

```
combineLatest(numpad1$, numpad2$, numpad3$).subscribe(console.log)
```

The subscription doesn't do a console log until numpad 1, 2 and 3 all have been pressed atleast once.
Is there an rxjs operator I can use to have an observable emit whenever any of the inner obersvables have emitted?
For example, in the example above, i'm expecting the `console.log` to be called when any numpad 1 is pressed for the first time, while numpad 2 and 3 haven't been pressed at all. So the result should be like this: [1, 0, 0] (0s because i'm using `startWith(0)`).

Comment: So you expect RxJs operator which return 0 if Observable doesn't emit. Or in other words - emit if it doesnt emit. There is no such operator.

Comment: You are on the right track with startWith, but you're filtering it right afterwards so it doesn't do anything.

Comment: move startWith to the end of each stream?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was actually to just move the `startWith(0)` to the end of the pipeline.
so:

```
const numpad1$ = fromEvent(document, 'keydown')
    .pipe(
        filter(({ key, code }) => key === '1' && code === 'Numpad1'),
        map(() => 1),
        scan((a, b) => a + b, 0),
        startWith(0),
    );
```

Answer (score -1):

The startsWith is filtered out by the filter operator, I suggest using a map function here. For instance:

```
const numpad3$ = fromEvent(document, 'keydown')
    .pipe(
        startWith(0),
        map(({ key, code }) => return key === '3' && code === 'Numpad3' ? 1 : 0)
    );
```

This will return one if it meets the conditions and 0 else.